# Date input without calendar

Tags: html, css, datepicker

The default html date input shows a text field and a option to see the calendar. For accessibility purpose, I need the field to show just the numeric input space and not the calendar option.

I have tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50052571/html-date-input-without-the-date-picker) but this only works for Chrome, IE and firefox still show the calendar.

Comment: You could make an input only allowing for the specific type of formatting, if the reference you mentioned didn't work, (since it is fairly recent), I don't think that using the pattern attribute will work.

Answer (score -1):

Since Date Fields have compatibility issues. It is better to work with raw HTML with custom CSS styling. I did it for my projects also and it work fine in many situations. You may try working with this code below.

```
<div class="DemoClass">
  <label for=""><strong>Date (dd/mm/yy)</strong></label>
  <input type="number" name="date" min="1" max="30">
  <input type="number" name="months" min="1" max="12">
  <input type="number" name="years" min="1900" max="2099">
</div>
```

Comment: The number field approach needs too much js validations for date including the number of days in a month, leap year, setting up date range which usually is prone to errors.